# Proof that the Following Deduction is Correct

Tags: logic, solution-verification, proof-writing

I need to proof that this deduction is correct:

> q → p ∧ r, p → s, p ∧ s → t ⇒ q → t

I'm allowed to use Modus Ponens, the Deduction Theorem and this axioms:

```
├ A → ( B → A)
├ (A → B) → ((A → (B → (B → C) ) → (A → C))
├ A → (B → A ∧ B)
├ A ∧ B → A,,    A ∧ B → B
├ A → A ∨ B,,    B → A ∨ B
├ (A → C) → ((B → C ) → (A ∨ B → C))
├ (A → B) → (( A → ~B) → ~A )
├ ~~A → A
```

I also use the Idempotent law, although I'd like to know if there is a way not to use it:

```
├ A ∧ A → A
```

So far this is what I've done:

```
1. ⊢ q → p ∧ r      premise 1
2. ⊢ p → s          premise 2
3. ⊢ p ∧ s → t      premise 3
4. ⊢ s ∧ s → t      MP 2,3
5. ⊢ s → t          Idempotent law 5
6. ⊢ p → t          MP 2,5
7. ⊢ q → t ∧ r      MP 1,6
```

I don't know how to continue from there, based on the premises there is nothing connecting the proposition `r` with the others, maybe I miss something while doing the proof, how would you do this?

Comment: Which axioms and inference rules are you allowed to use?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I've edited the question with more information.

Comment: Assume $q$ and apply MP a sufficient number of times; then conclude with DT.

Comment: Having said that, step 4 is wrong.

Comment: Step 6 is wrong.

Comment: Step 7 is wrong.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm not sure if I understand what do you mean by assume q

Comment: It means to produce the derivation: $q, q → p ∧ r, p → s, p ∧ s → t \vdash t$ and then apply DT to conclude with $q → t$